# Android intent chooser working but not sending file

Tags: android, file, share

So I am trying to share a text file in my app. The chooser appears and allows me to select an app, but regardless of what I choose to share the file with, there is always some sort of error that prevents the file from actually being sent. For example, Gmail says "Couldn't Attach File", and Facebook Messenger says "Error: Something went wrong. Try again later". Here is my code:

```
        val filePath = "/data/user/0/com.wellerstudios.doctrinalmastery/files/backup/Lists.txt"
        val file = File(filePath)
        val fileUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, "com.wellerstudios.fileprovider", file)
        Toast.makeText(context, fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent: Intent? = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            .setType("text/*")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via...")
        startActivity(chooser)
```

And both the file provider and filepath xml file match this code, so it's not that. Other people seem to use the same (or similar) code and have it work but mine doesn't and I don't know why. Also, its worth noting that I did use other forms for the filepath instead of specifying it via a string, but I was experimenting with it to see if that would fix my problem.

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. It is your content; you need to know what the proper MIME type is. Also, you probably should add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` both to your `Intent` and to the one created by `createChooser()`. You might look at Logcat and see if either of those apps are logging more details that you can use. And, if nothing else, you could create a scrap app that responds to `ACTION_SEND` and see if that app can use the stream.

Comment: I was using a concrete MIME type before, and it still didn't work. But I'll try the URI permission flag and the other stuff.

Comment: Nope, not working. I changed the MIME type back, added the permission to the chooser and checked logcat for any information (which didn't show up).